# Кодировка в JMS

Tags: java, кодировка, weblogic, jms

Как сделать кодировку *UTF-8* на *JMS*?

```
    TextMessage txmsg = session.createTextMessage();
    String myinput = request.getParameter("nameDocument");

    txmsg.setText(myinput);
    publisher.send(txmsg);
```

Это код с сервлета, на *SO* нашел такой метод но не смог реализовать

```
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    ((TextMessage) txmsg).getText().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailsession);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");
message.setContent(text, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
message.setFrom("no-reply@super.ac");
Transport.send(message);
```